# How do you set a "No fill" Fill on a autoshape with the PowerPoint 2010 interop

Tags: c#, ms-office, powerpoint, office-interop

I want to know how to set a newly added rectangle to have "No Fill" with the PowerPoint 2010 interop.

this is the code I have right now...

```
PowerPoint.Presentation presentation = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActivePresentation;
PowerPoint.Shape newshape = presentation.Slides[slideIndex].Shapes.AddShape(Office.MsoAutoShapeType.msoShapeRectangle, 72f, 72f, 72f, 72f);
newshape.Fill.Transparency = 1;
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to add

```
newshape.Fill.Visible = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse
```